# Python matplotlib - Apply 3D transform to Poly3DCollection

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, transform

I'm trying to animate (translate & rotate) a rigid 3D body using matplotlib. The 3D body is represented as a Poly3DCollection object.

In the 2D case you can use the set_transform method on LineCollection objects or other collections objects to achieve this.

Is there an equivalent for 3D collections?

I don't think [mplot3d.proj3d](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#module-mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.proj3d) offers a solution because this is about projecting 3D > 2D.

If no equivalent is available, what is the most efficient alternate solution?

Comment: Is transforming the underlying 3d points themselves an option? You could compute the affine transform manually, then use `poly.set_verts` on your `Poly3DCollection`.

Comment: I currently don't quite understand why you cannot use a transform here. You may want to elaborate on this point. As an alternative (which I would usually do even in 2D) you can simply change the data inside a loop/animating function.

Comment: matplotlib's transform functions only work for the 2D collections, not on 3D collections.

Iteratively unpacking, transforming and setting the vertices seems like the best option.

It is quite a complex Poly3DCollection coming from an STL file so I was hoping a built in transform function could be used